# Cannot convert value of type '(_, _, _) -> ()' to expected argument type 'Int64'

Tags: ios, alamofire

```
upload(urlRequest.1, with: urlRequest.0)
        Progress {(bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite) in // Error Comes Here
                print("\(Int64(totalBytesWritten)) / \(Int64(totalBytesExpectedToWrite))")
            }
            .responseJSON
            {
                response in

                hideLoading()

                showToast("Profile Updated Successfully!!")
            }
```

Comment: Do you really have `Progress`, not `.uploadProgress`?

Comment: i am using swift3 and alamofire -> 4.0

Comment: no its Progress if i put .uploadProgress it changes to Progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've replaced `.uploadProgress` with `Progress`, but have not changed the three parameters to the closure to be the single `Progress` parameter.

When you call `.uploadProgress`, the first parameter to that closure is a [`Progress`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/progress) (formerly known as `NSProgress`). But the Alamofire method name, `uploadProgress`, is unchanged. Only the parameters to the closure have changed.

Thus you want something like:

```
Alamofire.upload(data, with: request)
    .uploadProgress { progress in
        print(progress.fractionCompleted)
    }
    .responseJSON { response in
        self.hideLoading()

        switch response.result {
        case .failure(let error):
            self.showToast("Problem uploading: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        case .success:
            self.showToast("Profile Updated Successfully!!")
        }
}
```

Bottom line, the upload progress method is called `uploadProgress`, and it takes one parameter, a `NSProgress`/`Progress` object.

Comment: Showing me this error "Cannot call value of non-function type 'Progress' " on line :

Comment: Alamofire.upload(urlRequest.1, with: urlRequest.0)
            .uploadProgress { (bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite) in  // ERROR COMES HERE
                
                if (totalBytesWritten == totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
                {
                    
                }
                
                print("\(Int64(totalBytesWritten)) / \(Int64(totalBytesExpectedToWrite))")
              }

Comment: You're using three parameters to `.uploadProgress`, but there is actually only one parameter. See my example above.

Comment: then how can i add three parameters??

Comment: You don't. There is only one parameter in `uploadProgress` closure now, so you must use only one parameter. Frankly, it is much easier: Just look at the `fractionCompleted`. They've done the division for you. Again, see my example above. I don't get why you insist in trying to use three parameters.

Comment: ok thankx Rob This solution is worked for me i have passing wrong parameter that i understand later ... still thank you again